# Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I got this error in run time. These are code snippets of my code. I'm running Angular 9.

```
core.js:6237 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
    at DishdetailComponent.setPrevNext (dishdetail.component.ts:31)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (dishdetail.component.ts:26)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext (switchMap.js:70)
    at InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:11)
    at InnerSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at Notification.observe (Notification.js:20)
```

This is my dishdetail.component.ts file.

```
dish: Dish;
  dishIds : string[];
  prev: string;
  next: string;

  constructor(private dishService: DishService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private location: Location) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dishService.getDishIds().subscribe(dishIds => this.dishIds);
    this.route.params.pipe(switchMap((params: Params) => this.dishService.getDish(params['id']))).
    subscribe(dish => {this.dish=dish; this.setPrevNext(dish.id)});
  }

  setPrevNext(dishId: string){
    console.log(dishId);
    const index = this.dishIds.indexOf(dishId);
    this.prev = this.dishIds[(this.dishIds.length + index -1) % this.dishIds.length];
    this.next = this.dishIds[(this.dishIds.length+ index +1) % this.dishIds.length];
  }

  goBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }
```

`dishIds : string[]` is an array that contains string type id s of dishes. I need to iterate through the indexes of the array, then I implemented the setPrevNext method. And When run on the browser, it shows the above error. Please Help me. The browser shows the error is in 'indexof' in setPrevNext method.

Comment: What does `this.dishIds`  contain in `setPrevNext()` ? Is the value set there?

Comment: first of all you should initialize dishIds `dishIds: string[] = []` this will probably remove the error. But I assume it won't solve the problem itself.
I asume `setPrevNext` should be called when `getDishIds` and the route params have completed?
Your current problem is, that your code doesn't guarantee that dishIds is set. It might but it might also not be set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting you `dishIds` correctly in `ngOnInit`

Set `this.dishIds = dishIds` as following

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dishService.getDishIds().subscribe(dishIds => this.dishIds = dishIds);
    this.route.params.pipe(switchMap((params: Params) => 
    this.dishService.getDish(params['id']))).
      subscribe(dish => {this.dish=dish; this.setPrevNext(dish.id)});
  }
```

Comment: even so, the dishIds is async, it could be undefined when you run `setPrevNext`.

Comment: this solution might appear to work but actually doesn't always because of the async nature of rxjs

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the dishIds variable empty while defining or in the constructor.

```
dishIds: string[] = []
```

or

```
constructor(...) {
  this.dishIds = [];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

while initializing dishIds will prevent you from experiencing the error it won't solve the deeper problem which is using asynchronous code in a synchronous manner.

[I made a stackblitz to demonstrate the problem.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dfvxuq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)
You will see that `ids` is correctly filled wihle `ids2` is not because I added a delay.

If you use your code

```
 this.dishService.getDishIds().subscribe(dishIds => this.dishIds);
    this.route.params.pipe(switchMap((params: Params) => this.dishService.getDish(params['id']))).
    subscribe(dish => {this.dish=dish; this.setPrevNext(dish.id)});
```

I might work if `getDishIds` returns fast enough.
I added a delay in my example to simulate latency and you can see in my stackblitz that `ids2` is empty in `this.route.params`subscription.

That's because `this.route.params` is faster.

what you should do is combine the two streams so that you do your work as soon as you are sure you have all the data you need.

I used `combineLatest` which will be invoked as soon every observable has emitted a value.  Depending on your needs you might need something else.

here's how you can solve your problem

```
 combineLatest([this.dishService.getDishIds().subscribe(dishIds => this.dishIds),
    this.route.params.pipe(switchMap((params: Params) => this.dishService.getDish(params['id'])))]
    subscribe((value: [string[], dish: Dish]) => {
      //do your stuff
    });
```

additionally: Initialize your `dishIds` like `dishIds: string[] = []`
and for extra points ;) you could change your `setPrevNext` method so it takes the dishIds as parameter.
With that you won't create sideeffects in your stream.

Answer (score 0):

Here what you should do, and for more information try searching for rxjs, Observable and async code in js.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dishService.getDishIds().subscribe(dishIds => {
    this.dishIds = dishIds;
    // now you are sure that this.dishIds is defined.
    this.route.params.pipe(switchMap((params: Params) => 
    this.dishService.getDish(params['id']))).
    subscribe(dish => {
        this.dish=dish;
        this.setPrevNext(dish.id)});
    });
  }
```

Comment: nested subscription are considered an anti pattern. 
https://www.thinktecture.com/de/angular/rxjs-antipattern-1-nested-subs/

You can use something like `forkJoin`, `combineLatest` or `mergeMap` etc.